# How to enable Safari App Extension programmatically?

Tags: safari, macos-high-sierra, safari-app-extension

I'm developing a Safari App Extension inside a macOS app. When a user installs this app, the extension is added to Safari, but it's disabled by default. We can detect the state of extension by using [SFSafariExtensionManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager/2122754-getstateofsafariextensionwithide?language=objc) class via its getStateOfSafariExtension method.

Now I want to enable the extension state programmatically if it is disabled. How can I achieve that?
Or do anyone have any idea where the preferences / app extensions settings are stored in macOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a button such as "Open extension preferences" to show Safari preferences directly for your extension then the user could enable it.

The code for your app:

```
import SafariServices

func enableExtension () {
    SFSafariApplication.showPreferencesForExtension(withIdentifier: YOUR_EXTENSION_IDENTIFIER) { (error) in
        NSLog("Error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

`SFSafariApplication` could be used in Cocoa app only (not extension).

Comment: I already know that how to open extension preferences window by using SFSafariApplication class. I want to enable the extension without user interaction.

Comment: It is impossible due to security reasons. What if the extension could manage other extensions without user intent? Right, it is bad to give such abilities to extension.

Comment: @ВадимГолденко is there anyway to disable it through code or just like enabling, it is also restricted by apple?